# What's wrong with fish canned in oil?

Tags: diet, oil, fish

I found the following post on a food-related forum ([here](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/forum/thread10121.html#post141067)):

> Farmed fish do have omega 3 in them. They have a chunk of omega 6 too
>   so while they do have omega 3, they're not ideal for normalizing the
>   ratio. However there is a case in which sardine flesh is being sold
>   after the omega 3 has been extracted to make sardine oil. A good rule
>   of thumb is that the saturated fat should be about a quarter or less
>   of of the total fat if the tin doesn't specifically say that it has
>   omega 3. If saturated fat is a higher percentage of the sardine, the
>   omega 3 has been removed. Also be wary of fish canned in oil. Bad
>   news!

Why should we be wary of fish canned in oil?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely referring to the fact that canned fish is often packed in vegetable oils, which add fat content while not providing the omega-3 content of fish oil.

Comment: Ha. It didn't cross my mind that it might be that simple. Good thinking! Upvoted.

Comment: Though I must say that the phrasing "Also be wary of fish canned in oil. Bad news!" sounds pretty severe, I wonder if there's anything else to it.